# Dart socket listen doesn't wait until done

Tags: flutter, sockets, dart, stream, future

I would like to do these in a function:
1- connect socket
2- send query
3- listen data
4- return data

but when I tried the socket. listen function doesn't wait even I put await on it. It says it's not a future it's a Stream object but I have no idea about Streams so I'm stuck here. How can I do what I said?

```
static sendQuery({required String query,args, dimension}) async {
if(args != null)
  args.forEach((element) => query = query.replaceFirst("?", element));

String ip = shared.getData("remote_ip");
int port = shared.getData("remote_port");
String data =  "";
await Socket.connect(ip, port,timeout: Duration(seconds: 5)).then((soket) {
  soket.write(query);
  soket.listen((Uint8List buffer) async {
    String _buffer = String.fromCharCodes(buffer);
    data += _buffer;
  },
  onDone: () {});
});

print("Data has returned. Length of data: ${data.length}");
return data;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're `await`ing the result of the call to [`Socket.listen`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/listen.html), but that returns a [`StreamSubscription`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html), not a `Future`, and you can use `await` only on `Future`s.

You can, however, use [`StreamSubscription.asFuture`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/StreamSubscription/asFuture.html) to create a `Future` that will complete when the `Stream` completes normally or with an error.

Additionally, it's inconsistent to use both `.then()` and `await`.  Pick one; using `await` is usually more straightforward:

```dart
var socket = await Socket.connect(ip, port, timeout: Duration(seconds: 5));
soket.write(query);
var subscription = soket.listen((Uint8List buffer) async {
  String _buffer = String.fromCharCodes(buffer);
  data += _buffer;
});
await subscription.asFuture<void>();
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked for me. And I have a question more. How can I decode the coming data? When I print or just add my local database the _buffer data, the characters which are not asciii ones coming incorrect.

Comment: @Ertuğrul Çakıcı Depends on how the data is encoded.  If it's UTF-8, you should use [`utf8.decode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/Utf8Codec/decode.html).